# Convert IP or MAC address from string to byte array (Arduino or C)

Tags: c, arduino, byte, arrays

I would convert myString "100.200.300.400" to byte array [4].
I'm a "bit" confused, this is right or need i to use a foreach for reading a single number?

```
String myString = "100.200.300.400";
byte myByteArray[4];
myString.getBytes(myByteArray,4);
```

Finally I want to print to the array to serial. This should be right.

```
for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
  Serial.print(myByteArray[i]);
  Serial.print("."); //delimiter
}
```

Were I am going wrong? I got 49,48,48,0 !

Comment: 49 is the Ascii for the character "1", 48 is for "0" and so on. So you are getting what would be  expected.

Comment: If you're trying to convert that to a byte array, it sounds like you just want the numbers.  The problem is that you have two numbers greater than 255 and you can't store a number that large into a single byte.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer The fundamental problem is that the OP is trying to convert strings to numbers, and not string to byte array, as he sees it.

Comment: Many thanks guys. Numbers "300" and "400" are only for an example. Numbers will be limited from 0 to 255. So how can i loop for a String like "50.100.150.200" ?

Comment: You need to *parse* this string. Look at `atoi` function. And the Arduino's `String` object has some useful methods: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject

Comment: @Davide please edit your question and make clear what you would like to be printed to the serial port.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are trying to get from a string like `"100.150.200.250"` to a byte array like `{ 100, 150, 200, 250 }`, you need to extract the string representation for each number and convert (parse) them into a binary representation before storing them in the byte array.

The way you are trying to do this, you are just converting the first four bytes from the string, i.e. `"100."`, to the binary representation of each character, which turns out to be `{ 49, 48, 48, 0 }`. You can look that up in an [ASCII table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_code_chart).

Also remember that, as you are storing this on a byte array, it will only support values from 0 to 255.

As you are programming on small microcontroller, I would advise against using the `String` class. You might run into trouble when your programs get bigger and you start using lots of strings. Try to learn how to use character arrays instead and you will avoid running into memory issues. Remember the Arduino has just 2KB of RAM!

Here is a function you can use to make that conversion using the `strtoul()` function:

```
void parseBytes(const char* str, char sep, byte* bytes, int maxBytes, int base) {
    for (int i = 0; i < maxBytes; i++) {
        bytes[i] = strtoul(str, NULL, base);  // Convert byte
        str = strchr(str, sep);               // Find next separator
        if (str == NULL || *str == '\0') {
            break;                            // No more separators, exit
        }
        str++;                                // Point to next character after separator
    }
}
```

You can then call it like this to convert an IP address (base 10):

```
const char* ipStr = "50.100.150.200";
byte ip[4];
parseBytes(ipStr, '.', ip, 4, 10);
```

Or like this to convert a MAC address (base 16):

```
const char* macStr = "90-A2-AF-DA-14-11";
byte mac[6];
parseBytes(macStr, '-', mac, 6, 16);
```

Comment: if i have a MAC Address like "90-A2-AF-DA-14-11" could i use the same function? I think not because i don't need the byte conversion (MAC address il already hexadecimal). Wrong?

Comment: @Davide I changed the function a bit to handle different number bases and added an example with a MAC address.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `sscanf`, and by the way detect invalid inputs using [its return value](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/#return):

```
byte ip[4];
if (sscanf(mString.c_str(), "%hhu.%hhu.%hhu.%hhu", ip, ip+1, ip+2, ip+3) != 4) {
  Serial.print("invalid IP: ");
  Serial.println(mString);
}
```

However, `sscanf` may not be implemented in the library for all boards, for example on esp8266 it's [yet to be released](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/488#issuecomment-195364848) in version 2.4.0.

Also, the `%hhu` specifier for `unsigned char` may be not supported in some versions, but you can use `%u`, read it to an `unsigned long` and check if the value isn't greater than 255.